Lower Bound on the Components of $A^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \cdots 1 \end{bmatrix}^T$ for any Invertible $(0,1)$-Matrix
Let $A$ be an invertible $n\times n$ matrix with entries consisting only of $0$s and $1$s, such that
$$
A\cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ \vdots \\ b_n \end{bmatrix}.$$
Prove or disprove that if all components of $A^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ are positive, then all components are greater than or equal to $ \frac{1}{\max_{i=1}^n b_i} $.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This is not correct. Counterexamples exist when $n=5$. Please at least do a numerical experiment before posting your question.

Thank you very much for your comment. Based on your suggestions, I have found a counterexample for n=5. I am sorry for the insufficiency of my numerical experiment.

The conjecture is wrong.
There exists a counterexample when $n=5$:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Thanks to @user1551's comment.
